# Culture setting, month is reverted with day

Tags: c#

I have problem reading values from excel, my local time setting is `MM/dd/YYYY` while I would like to read as `dd/MM/YYYY` as it is in excel. Unfortunally somehow application is transforming values from excel into my local time, I tried to use this

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("pl-PL");
```

While polish culture is `dd/MM/YYYY` but it doesn't help , what can I do ?

To read excel I use interoop like this :

```
var application = new Application();
var workbooks = application.Workbooks;
var workbook = workbooks.Open(file);
```

and then save as cvs and read csv to read it faster

```
var tempFile = file.Substring(0, file.Length - 4) + ".csv";

workbook.SaveAs(tempFile, XlFileFormat.xlCSVWindows);

var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(tempFile));
reader.ReadLine();

while (!reader.EndOfStream)
```

and the problem is that with BE locale I got 2/25/2013 and if I set to PL I got 25/2/2013 i would to have second value always.

Comment: How are you retrieving the values from Excel?  Are you interacting with Excel directly, or just reading from a CSV or XLS?  Please show whatever code you have for how you read the data.

Comment: It would be useful to see the line of code that is causing the issue. Are you using a DateTime.Parse() function to do this or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are getting the Date as String from Excel in the form of `MM/dd/yyyy` you can convert to `dd/MM/yyyy`.

You need to parse the Date String from excel using `DateTime.ParseExact()` method as below:

Try This:

```
        String date = "02/21/2014";
        DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        date=dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Comment: In the last line you don't pass `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` again to the `ToString` method. You don't "escape" the slash `/` character either. That means that the slash will substituted with whatever string is the date separator of the current `CultureInfo`. Is that intended?